# How to correctly format outbound GET requests that contain data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, https

I am working on the backend of my iOS game and I want to validate Facebook logins on my server before I send any data back to the client. I have a valid app_access token provided by Facebook and I am able to successfully enter the following link in my browser to debug/validate access tokens:

https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=users_access_token&access_token=apps_access_token

Ofcourse the correct access tokens are placed in the placeholders. From that request I receive a response that looks something like this:

```
{
   "data": {
      "app_id": app_id,
      "is_valid": true,
      "application": "My App",
      "user_id": user_id,
      "expires_at": 1382468400,
      "scopes": [
         "email",
         "publish_actions",
         "user_birthday",
         "user_location"
      ]
   }
}
```

From which I am able to determine if the user has a correct access token. However, trying to implement this from the server side has been fruitless. Here is how I am trying now

```
var http = require('http'); 
var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var data = querystring.stringify({
    'access_token': app_access_token,
    'input_token': user_access_token
});

console.log('' + data); //Debug to see if data is correctly formatted

var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/debug_token',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Which always returns me the following response:

```
body: {"error":{"message":"(#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

I have noticed that the querystring does tend to format the "|" into "%7C" but I have manually replaced the characters and the data string to no avail. Is there something I am doing wrong? The tokens are correct, I just cant seem to format the data correctly.

**Edit**

Finally got it working. Michaels solution is right. I tried the same solution earlier and it didnt work because I performed a http.request() instead of an https.request() and I forgot to try it again. Such a silly mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GET` parameters are passed as a query string, part of path `/path?param1=val1&param2=val2`. In your case

```
path: '/debug_token?'+data,
```

instead of `req.write(data)`.